# Cannot install pip packages due to locale.error inside Ubuntu Vagrant Box

Tags: python, ubuntu, vagrant, pip, virtualenv

I just created a vagrant box with ubuntu/trusty32. The vagrant provisioner, during box creation time, has done the following:

- downloaded python virtualenv source tarball using `wget`
- untarred the virtualenv source tarball using `tar zxvf ./virtualenv.tar.gz`
- created a virtualenv called `venv` using `python ./virtualenv/virtualenv.py ./venv`
- sourced the newly created venv with `source ./venv/bin/activate`
- installed a few pip packages with `pip install django`, `pip install mysqlclient` etc inside the virtual environment.

**All of this worked fine and perfect** - executed by the vagrant provisioner when the vagrant box was being created for the first time.

However, later on, i logged in to the vagrant ssh and tried to install `ipython` via `pip`.

```
$ vagrant ssh
vagrant@django-box:~$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) vagrant@django-box:~$ pip install ipython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 215, in main
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 579, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
(venv) vagrant@django-box:~$
```

*Note: this is a fresh new vagrant box running ubuntu/trusty32 out of the box.*

There are several SO questions about locale error but following them revealed no help for this vagrant scenario.

It doesn't make sense that ***all of it worked perfectly fine during vagrant box creation/provision time but not working afterwards when trying the same thing manually***.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First check your current **locale** config by simply putting `locale` in command line.

You should see something similar to:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=C
LC_CTYPE=utf8
```

Set a valid locale in the LC_CTYPE environment variable by running the following commands:

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

PS. `en_US.UTF-8` is used here but if you need to check all available locales on your system, run the command `locale -a`

This should solve the problem.

Comment: great... this worked... .what just happened???

is there any difference between wrapping `en_US.UTF-8` inside quotes and not wrapping `en_US.UTF-8` inside quotes?

Comment: note.. i am needing to do this every time i am logging into the machine's shell. How do i make it permanent?

Comment: You can add the commands in `.bashrc` and that way it will get executed each time you log into your shell. And also don't forget to mark this as answer so that anyone else having the problem can consider it as answer :)

Comment: still don't understand why it worked fine by the vagrant provisioner but not when trying it manually